# How can I achieve this kind of auto-incrementation in a MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, jdbc, indexing

I have one table called `animal`.

In this table there are four columns

1. Animal
2. AnimalIndex
3. Breed
4. BreedIndex

All four of this columns should be the `primary key`
I would like them to auto-increment logically this means getting something like this.

```
| Animal| AI | Breed  | BI |
----------------------------
| dog   | 1  | Akita  | 1  |
| cat   | 2  | Persan | 1  |
| dog   | 1  | Barbet | 2  |
| dog   | 1  | Boxer  | 3  |
| eagle | 3  | Bald   | 1  |
```

so if I enter a query of type

```
INSERT INTO animal (Animal, Breed) VALUES("dog", "Akita")
```

my indexes would automatically increment. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you forced to use this data model? This is kind of ignoring the "relational" part of the relational database that you are using.

Comment: can you provide an alternative? Perhaps you mean using two different tables?

Comment: This is madness.

Comment: @Havenard why is that?

Comment: Fixing this madness is exactly why we use unique IDs on things. One number that represents a record, life made easy. Whenever you decide you need a multi field primary key, I suggest you consider you're doing something wrong.

Comment: What is the purpose of the breed_idx?

Comment: MyISAM used to implement such.  There are many questions on this forum asking for it in InnoDB.  And some of them have workarounds.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: @Havenard it just seemed more logic to me I wanted to query by index instead of string and  I am not really good at database so.

Comment: @danblack I mean how do you link both category and sub category logically using two different ID, I don't really get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using a different data model. Perhaps something more relational friendly:

Animal:

```
| id | name  |
--------------
| 1  | dog   |
| 2  | cat   |
| 3  | eagle |
```

Breed:

```
| id | name    | breed_idx | animal_id |
---------------------------------------|
| 1  | Akita   | 0         | 1         |
| 2  | Persan  | 0         | 2         |
| 3  | Barbet  | 1         | 1         |
| 4  | Boxer   | 2         | 1         |
| 5  | Bald    | 1         | 3         |
```

Mysql can easily take care of auto-incrementing the id columns, but since the "breed_idx" column requires a bit of logic, you will have to take care of that yourself. One way you could accomplish it is by using a select in your inserts:

```
insert into breed (name, breed_idx, animal_id) values('Shar pei', (select count(*) from breed where animal_id = (select id from animal where name = 'dog')), (select id from animal where name = 'dog'));
```

Note that this would create a zero-indexed column, as my sample data above indicates.

There are other ways you could do this (stored procedures or triggers), but this is a quick, and database-provider agnostic way to achieve what (I think) you are looking for.

Comment: thanks I will try that and if it works make sure I'll mark it as answer. Thx again

Answer (score 2):

Please note the solution explained by @rmlan is quite useful, simple, and database agnostic. However, it may not work well in enterprise level applications, specially under heavy insertion rate.

In those cases, parallel threads could produce the same id.

For those cases, I would suggest using a trigger.